# if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to change render function and run some sub render function when a specific state given,

For example:

```
render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            if (this.state == 'news'){
                return (
                    <Text>data</Text>
                )
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

How can I implement that without changing scenes, I will use tabs to change content dynamically.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

As per **[DOC](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html)**:

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just
>   syntactic sugar for function calls and object construction.

Basic Rule:

> JSX is fundamentally [syntactic sugar](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html). After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript function calls and evaluate to JavaScript objects. We can embed any [JavaScript expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) in JSX by wrapping it in curly braces.

But only expressions not statements, means directly we can not put any statement (*if-else/switch/for*) inside [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

---

If you want to render the element conditionally then use `ternary operator`, like this:

```
render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.state.value == 'news'? <Text>data</Text>: null }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Another option is, call a function from `jsx` and put all the `if-else` logic inside that, like this:

```
renderElement(){
   if(this.state.value == 'news')
      return <Text>data</Text>;
   return null;
}

render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            { this.renderElement() }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: can I do like that?   render() {
    return (
   
      <View style={styles.container}>


if (this.state == 'news'){
return (
<Text>data</Text>

)
}

Comment: so return inside return is possible? or two different returns in same render function scene I need to change sub content of return

Comment: yes that is possible but, in a different way directly we can't use if/else inside JSX so use ternary operator for conditions, use this: `render() { 
 return ( 
  <View style={styles.container}> 
   {this.state == 'news' ? <Text>data</Text> : null }
  </View>
 )
}`

Comment: `  <Text style={styles.instructions}>
              {
 if (this.state.page == 'sohbet'){


} ` not possible?

}
          </Text>

Comment: that is well explained in doc, check this for reason: http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Comment: 404 but how can I call a function rather than a text in here  this.state.page == 'sohbet' ?
 <Text>data</Text>

 :null

Comment: it was working don't know what's the issue,reason is: The content of {...} must be an expression, if-else/for/switch are statements. yes you can do one thing you can call a function and put the if/else inside that, will update the answer :)

Comment: ..return <Text>{res.text()}</Text>... that function returns this but it show nothing is that wrong I nee to return jsx code from this function

Comment: what is `res.text()` ? if `test` is a name of function then you need to call that by using `this.text()`, not by res can you show the full code it will be easy to help you, check the updated answer how to call the function.

Comment: its just text   //alert(res.text());
 works but not returning anything to text inside

Comment: pulldata() {
return <Text>aaa</Text>

// send http request in a new thread (using native code)
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'http://bigpaaasasas', {
   // Authorization : 'Bearer access-token...',
    // more headers  ..
  })
  // when response status code is 200
  .then((res) => {
    // the conversion is done in native code
  //  let base64Str = res.base64()
    //alert(res.text());

// this.state = {page: res.text()};
return <Text>aaa</Text>

Comment: its a asyn call it will not return the updated div directly, you need to use the state variable, like this: `pulldata() {   
  RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'bigpaaasasas';, { 
   Authorization : 'Bearer access-token...', 
  }) 
  .then((res) => {
   let base64Str = res.base64()  
   this.setState({page: res.text()});
  })
}

render() { 
 return ( 
  <View style={styles.container}> 
   <Text>{this.state.page == 'news' ? : this.state.page : 'aaa'</Text>
  </View>
 )
}`

Comment: set the data in state variable and once you do setState it will update the ui, and check the condition inside render method.

Comment: Great, https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html this helps me

Answer (score 68):

You can achieve what you are saying by using Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)

```
render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {(() => {
              if (this.state == 'news'){
                  return (
                      <Text>data</Text>
                  )
              }
              
              return null;
            })()}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Here is the working example:

[image: Edit awesome-yalow-eb2nu]

But, In your case, you can stick with the ternary operator

Comment: @Yusufbek can you help me why in this part " if (this.state == 'news'){
                  return (<div><Text> data1</Text>
                      <Text>data2</Text></siv>
                  )
              }"  doesnt work

Comment: meaning in the above return we use div for mutliple elemnts 2 text

Comment: @AakashMathur it should work. Make sure you are returning only 1 root element and you have else statement to return null

Comment: You can achieve a much more intuitive solution by switching to Vue. It boggles my mind that such a hack has to be done for something so fundamental.

Answer (score 41):

I find this way is the nicest:

```
{this.state.yourVariable === 'news' && <Text>{data}<Text/>}
```

Comment: I agree, this is the nicest of the bunch. Returning `null` with a ternary-operator is unnecessary ;)

Comment: This should be added to the main answer.

Comment: How could I use this in my case? If I use it like this ```{localStorage.getItem('token') && <Typography>Invalid Login</Typography>}```it will be rendered even before the form is submitted. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577971/conditional-rendering-inside-a-function

Comment: This helped me in my case, however, I had to wrap elements in <>...</>.

Comment: This works well if you do not need a false-case outcome which the ternary syntax can provide.

Answer (score 14):

I do like this and its working fine.

```
constructor() {
   super();

   this.state ={
     status:true
   }
}

render() {
   return( 

     { this.state.status === true ?
           <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this.hideView()}>
             <View style={styles.optionView}>
               <Text>Ok Fine :)</Text>
             </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
           :
           <Text>Ok Fine.</Text>
     }
  );
}

hideView(){
  this.setState({
    home:!this.state.status
  });
}
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Instead of if-else, you can use ternary operators in render() method. Syntax :- condition ? expr1 : expr2 

Ex. if (this.state.status === true) {
    
      } else { 

     }

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use an conditional statement in functional component then you can call a function from jsx and put all your conditional logic inside it.

```
conditionalRender(){
   if(state === 'news') {
      return <Text>data</Text>;
   }
   else(state !== 'news') {
      return <Text>Static Value</Text>;
   }
}

render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            { conditionalRender() }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: error: signature declaration only works in typescript files :(

Answer (score 3):

You can do this. Just don't forget to put "return" before your JSX component.

Example:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.page === 'news') {
        return <Text>This is news page</Text>;
    } else {
        return <Text>This is another page</Text>;
    }
}
```

Example to fetch data from internet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            bodyText: ''
        }
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch('https://example.com').then((resp) => {
            this.setState({
                bodyText: resp._bodyText
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        return <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>{this.state.bodyText}</Text>
        </View>
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me a little full working example sorry I am new to this

Comment: @user8026867 example added

Comment: i want to return from inside a function

Comment: @user8026867 you can make a function and return the JSX component there. Try it and see if you can make it otherwise I'll give you an example.

Comment: alert works ok but not rendering happens after .then

how can I do that

pulldata() {
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'http://bigcom', {
     })
  .then((res) => {
    alert(res.text());

return <Text>{res.text()}</Text>

  })
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
alert(errorMessage);
  })

}

Comment: @user8026867 You shouldn't fetch data like this. I've added an example on how to fetch data from the internet and show it in your render method. You should use states wherever you want your data to be dynamic. And moreover do not call functions in the render method as render method keeps re-rendering multiple times, which may result in calling the same function multiple times unnecessarily. I hope this helps

Comment: {
 this.state.page == 'haberler' ?
this.pulldata();
return <Text>{this.state.bodyTexts}</Text>
 :null
}

Answer (score 3):

There's a Babel plugin that allows you to write conditional statements inside JSX without needing to escape them with JavaScript or write a wrapper class.  It's called [JSX Control Statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements):

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <If condition={ this.state == 'news' }>
    <Text>data</Text>
  </If>
</View>
```

It takes a bit of setting up depending on your Babel configuration, but you don't have to import anything and it has all the advantages of conditional rendering without leaving JSX which leaves your code looking very clean.

Answer (score 2):

**What about switch case instead of if-else**

```
  render() {
    switch (this.state.route) {
      case 'loginRoute':
        return (
            <Login changeRoute={this.changeRoute}
              changeName={this.changeName}
              changeRole={this.changeRole} />
        );
      case 'adminRoute':
        return (
            <DashboardAdmin
              role={this.state.role}
              name={this.state.name}
              changeRoute={this.changeRoute}
            />
        );
      default: 
        return <></>;
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a default return value, which should be something else than `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <Card style={
  { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', 
    height: 150, width: 250, paddingTop: 10 }}>
                                
<Text style={styles.title}> 
 {item.lastName}, {item.firstName} ({item.title})
</Text> 
<Text > Email: {item.email}</Text>
 {item.lastLoginTime != null ? 
   <Text >  Last Login: {item.lastLoginTime}</Text> 
   : <Text >  Last Login: None</Text>
 }
 {
   item.lastLoginTime != null ? <Text >  
   Status: Active</Text> : <Text > Status: Inactive</Text>
 }                              
</Card>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the `if else` condition in JSX. It provides a function like ternary operator to make the thing happen for you, example:

```js
state={loading:false}
<View>
  {loading ? <Text>This is a test For if else condition</Text> : <ActivityIndicator/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 render() {
     return (   
         <View style={styles.container}>
         (() => {                                                       
             if (this.state == 'news') {
                return  <Text>data</Text>
            }
            else 
             return  <Text></Text>
        })()
         </View>
     )
 }
```

https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of nested loop with if condition in **React**:

Data example:

```
    menus: [
    {id:1, name:"parent1", pid: 0},
    {id:2, name:"parent2", pid: 0},
    {id:3, name:"parent3", pid: 0},
    {id:4, name:"parent4", pid: 0},
    {id:5, name:"parent5", pid: 0},
    {id:6, name:"child of parent 1", pid: 1},
    {id:7, name:"child of parent 2", pid: 2},
    {id:8, name:"child of parent 2", pid: 2},
    {id:9, name:"child of parent 1", pid: 1},
    {id:10, name:"Grand child of parent 2", pid: 7},
    {id:11, name:"Grand child of parent 2", pid: 7},
    {id:12, name:"Grand child of parent 2", pid: 8},
    {id:13, name:"Grand child of parent 2", pid: 8},
    {id:14, name:"Grand child of parent 2", pid: 8},
    {id:15, name:"Grand Child of Parent 1 ", pid: 9},
    {id:15, name:"Child of Parent 4 ", pid: 4},
    ]
```

Nested Loop and Condition:

```
    render() {
    let subMenu='';
    let ssubmenu='';
    const newMenu = this.state.menus.map((menu)=>{
    if (menu.pid === 0){
    return (
    <ul key={menu.id}>
       <li>
          {menu.name}
          <ul>
             {subMenu = this.state.menus.map((smenu) => {
             if (menu.id === smenu.pid) 
             {
             return (
             <li>
                {smenu.name}
                <ul>
                   {ssubmenu = this.state.menus.map((ssmenu)=>{
                   if(smenu.id === ssmenu.pid)
                   {
                   return(
                   <li>
                      {ssmenu.name}
                   </li>
                   )
                   }
                   })
                   }
                </ul>
             </li>
             )
             }
             })}
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
    )
    }
    })
    return (
    <div>
       {newMenu}
    </div>
    );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide if-else condition in the return block, make use of ternary block, also this.state will be an object, you shouldn't be comparing it with a value, see which state value you want to check, also return returns only one element, make sure to wrap them in a View

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.page === 'news'? <Text>data</Text>: null}
      </View>

     )
}
```

Comment: My mistake, didn't see the react-native tag, it should be View and not div

Comment: btw I need to return text after RNFetchBlob function

Comment: pulldata() {
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'http://bigdsas', {
     })
  .then((res) => {
    alert(res.text());

return <Text>aaaf</Text>

  })
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
alert(errorMessage);
  })
return <Text>iop</Text>



}

Answer (score 0):

In two ways we can solve this problem:

1. Write a else condition by adding just empty `<div>` element.
2. or else return null.

```js
render() {
    return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
            if (this.state == 'news'){
                return (
                    <Text>data</Text>
                );
            }
            else {
                 <div> </div>
            }

        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Tried that:

```
return(
  <>
    {
      main-condition-1 && 
      main-condition-2 &&
      (sub-condition ? (<p>Hi</p>) : (<p>Hello</p>))
     }
  </>
)
```

Let me know what you guys think!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just Write Down The Code

```
 <> 
    {row.photo != null ? <img src={serverPath(row.photo)} className='img-fluid shadow-4' alt="" /> : ''}
 </>
```

---

Comment: Please add supporting info to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

For this we can use ternary operator or if there is only one condition then "&&" operator .Like this:-

```
//This is for if else

render() {

return (   
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state == 'news') ?
           <Text>data</Text>
        : null}
    </View>
)
```

}

```
//This is only for if or only for one condition

render() {

return (   
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state == 'news') &&
           <Text>data</Text>
        }
    </View>
)
```

}