# Conditional Rendering in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added a condition in rendering and suddenly it stops displaying. Here is the code  am using.

```
 {this.state.sdata.map((sdata, i) => 
   {i < 5 && 
    <ServiceNavItem key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleSelect(i)}{...sdata} /> 
   }
  )
 }
```

I want to display only 4 items from sdata. Anybody please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the element from `map` body, as well as you need to `return null` for all the entries of `array` after **i >= 5**.

Write it like this:

```
{this.state.sdata.map((sdata, i) => {
       if(i < 5) 
          return <ServiceNavItem key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleSelect(i)}{...sdata} /> 
       return null;
   })
}
```

But i will suggest you to use `for loop` instead of `map` to create only 5 elements.

If you want to use `map` then first use [**slice**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and create a sub `array` of 5 elements then use `map` on that.

Like this:

```
{this.state.sdata.slice(0,5).map((sdata, i) => {
     return <ServiceNavItem key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleSelect(i)}{...sdata} /> 
})}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
{this.state.sdata.map((sdata, i) => 
     (i < 4 && 
       <ServiceNavItem key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleSelect(i)}{...sdata} /> 
     )
   )
}
```

Just replace the `{}` with `()` like shown above and to show 4 data you have to provide less than 4 because i starts with 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try alternatives of conditional rendering from here: [Conditional Rendering in React and the JSX solution](https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/conditional-rendering-in-react-and-jsx-the-solution-7c80beba1e36)

Basically, the proposal is to create a "Conditional" Component, and use it like:

```
<Conditional if={this.state.something}>
  <div>hello!</div>
<Conditional>
```

So, `<div>hello!</div>` is going to be rendered only if `this.state.something` is true.

In your example, it should be implemented in this way:

```
{
  this.state.sdata.map((sdata, i) => 
    <Conditional if={i < 5}>
      <ServiceNavItem key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleSelect(i)}{...sdata} /> 
    </Conditional>
}
```

Anyways, the best way to show only 5 elements is to do:
Basically, get only the first 5 elements from the array and do a `.map` in that `Array`.

```
{
  this.state.sdata.slice(0, 5).map((sdata, i) => 
    <ServiceNavItem key={i} onClick={()=>this.handleSelect(i)}{...sdata} /> 
  );
}
```