# Conditional rendering question with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use a `<Conditional if={condition}>` component in React, that renders its content only if the condition is true.

I've used the code from [here](https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/conditional-rendering-in-react-and-jsx-the-solution-7c80beba1e36), as mentioned in Broda Noel's response of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649698/conditional-rendering-in-react-js). You also see the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/m369jw158y).

```
import * as React from 'react';

const Conditional = props => (
    !!props.if && props.children
);

class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const item = { id: 2 };

        return (
            <>
                <h2>Item detail</h2>
                {/* Display item.foo.name if `foo` property exists */}
                <Conditional if={item.foo}>
                    {item.foo.name}
                </Conditional>
            </>);
    }
}

export default Item;
```

It fails with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I know I can also use `{item.foo && item.foo.name}`, but when the code becomes more complex, I find the use of `Conditional` more readable. And most important, I would really like to understand what happens here.

Why does React render the content of the Conditional, even is the condition is false?
Is there a way to change the Conditional component to make it work in this case?

I'm using React 16.4.1, with typescript.

Comment: Try to set the if to `if={item.foo !== undefined} `. Your if have no condition, comparison or anything like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
<Conditional if={item.foo}>
  {item.foo.name}
</Conditional>
```

is transpiled to:

```
React.createElement(Condition, { if: item.foo }, item.foo.name)
```

So even if the condition is false it will try to access the property `name`.

I suggest that you use the code below when the code becomes more complex:

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Item extends React.Component {
  renderConditional (item) {
    if (!item.foo) {
      return null;
    }
    return item.foo.name; // Or some jsx
  }

  render() {
    const item = { id: 2 };

    return (
      <>
        <h2>Item detail</h2>
        {this.renderConditional(item)}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

You could also create another component to present the data and check the object inside the new component.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your component `<Conditional>` have no logical expression in the `if` prop. The "React way" to do this is using conditional rendering as is:

```
render() {
    const item = { id: 2 };

    return (
      <>
        <h2>Item detail</h2>
        { item.foo !== undefined &&  // React Way to Conditional Rendering
          {item.foo.name}
        }
      </>
    );
}
```

I recommend you to read the docs for [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)