# React - conditionally render multiple elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a slider and I want to only show the arrows if the slider has more than one image.

I've tried something like the following in the return

```
{(this.state.images > 1)
  <LeftArrow goToPrevSlide={this.goToPrevSlide} />
  <RightArrow goToNextSlide={this.goToNextSlide} />
}
```

and I get the following `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"`

Comment: Of course, I always research before asking thanks, also this isn't a duplicate...

Comment: `{[<LeftArrow key="left" goToPrevSlide={this.goToPrevSlide} />,
  <RightArrow key="right" goToNextSlide={this.goToNextSlide} />].filter(() => this.state.images > 1)}` could work in this case, though a bit ugly looking (and renders the arrows even when they're not used)

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickRoberts that works, can you explain what's going on in the code so I can understand it? Looks like a filter array

Comment: `{this.state.images > 1 && ...}` You'll also need to wrap your two child components with a single parent. You can use a Fragment `<>...</>` or a `<div>` or w/e.

Comment: it is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44649698/104380

Comment: @vsync I would say this is different (but maybe seen as splitting hairs), since this is asking how to inline conditionally render multiple elements, while the linked duplicates don't suggest a way (but do suggest a way via an `if/else` statement and a ternary operator.

Answer (score 21):

You **must** wrap both your elements in some **container**. This container is treated as a "whole", no matter what is inside it. In this example below I am using an empty [Fragment container](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

Also, notice that only the piece of code written *directly* after the `&&` is executed if the first part, before the `&&` was resolved as `true`. ([Read more about `&&`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8720645/104380).

This is why you must wrap everything which should be conditionally-rendered in a container, because if you didn't, only the first element would have been conditionally rendered and anything after it would always get rendered

```
{ this.state.images > 1 && <>
  <LeftArrow goToPrevSlide={this.goToPrevSlide} />
  <RightArrow goToNextSlide={this.goToNextSlide} />
 </>
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already had everything in a fragment container, wasn't aware that I had to include another one for a conditional. Noted

Comment: @nightcode - You did not use the javascript `&&` sign to signal what comes after it should run only if the first part of the statement is true

Comment: @vsync RE: `Stackoverflow doesn't allow updating the linked to a duplicate once it has been set` [_yes it does_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYzxG.png)

Comment: That's not new, [it's been around long before the recent design changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/313880).