# React JS getting started issue

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Hi I am stuck with this issue, am just getting started with react js. Its the HOME js component 
when button is clicked I want to show some text ( when flag is true) else it should show nothing.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component{

 constructor(props)
 {
    super(props);
    this.state = {flag: false}
    this.showMe = this.showMe.bind(this);

 }
showMe()
 {
   this.state.flag ? ((<div> show this when flag is true </div>) : null)
 }


render()
{

    return(
        <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website {this.state.flag}</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick={this.showMe}>Click me </button>


  </div>);
}

}
```

Error on console:

```
16:2:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ":"

  14 |  {
  15 |    this.state.flag ? ((<div> show this when flag is true</div>) : null)
> 16 |  }
     |  ^
  17 |
  18 |
  19 | render()
```

Comment: You've got unbalanced parentheses which is what the error tells you. It looks like a simple typo.

Comment: Once the typo fixed, the answer you've got is just explaining what's in this other popular question [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44046037/1218980)

Answer (score 3):

You want the `showMe` handler to only change state.

the return body of `showMe` should instead be returned in the `render` function since you are returning JSX/HTML.

```
showMe() { 
  this.setState({flag: !this.state.flag})
}

render()
{

    return(
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website {this.state.flag}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.showMe}>Click me </button>
      {this.state.flag ? ((<div> show this when flag is true </div>) : null)}

    </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: I tried your changes didnt work.
when I click on button if the flag is true then it should show some text else nothing. thanks for quick response.

Comment: Correct. I edited the `showMe` method to change state

Comment: I did, but it says I need to wait for 5 mins : )