# (React) How to render component only if condition is met

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to render a child component only if a condition is met but no matter what I try, nothing really works. I get all sort of errors.

My application is a store than contains a list of fruits available to clients. I want to render only the items selected into their basket. That's what Facture.js is trying to do. I'm trying to check the count of every fruits in the list that has `count > 0` and nothing when it's 0.

Right now, it's rendering everything in the list, even though I do not want them – I know in this actual code there is no condition, so it returns everything.

*Shouldn't it just be as simple as an if block?*

---

Here is my full code structure if it helps :

**App.js**

```
import Client from "./Client";

state = { fruits : [{name: "Apple", price: "3", count: 2}, 
                    {name: "Orange", price: "2", count: 0}] }

render() { <Client fruits={this.state.fruits}/> }

// I tried this : {this.props.fruits.count > 0 ? <Factures fruits={this.props.fruits} /> : null} but it returns nothing.
```

**Client.js**

```
import Factures from "./Factures";
render() { <Factures fruits={this.props.fruits}/> }
```

**Factures.js**

```
import Facture from "./Facture";
render() {
      return this.props.fruits.map(fruit => <Facture key={fruit.nom} fruit={fruit} /> );
}
```

**Facture.js**

```
class Facture extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <li className='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between small'>
            <div className=''>{this.props.fruit.name}</div>
            <div className=''>{'x' + this.props.fruit.count}</div>
         </li>
      );
   }
}

export default Facture;
```

Comment: I think you need to add more detail. For instance, you talk about a list but I don't see one. What do you want to render if `count <= 0`, nothing?

Comment: You could do like Luke answer's says, and just return `false` or `null` from a render to render nothing. But a better idea is to control whether it's rendered at all from the parent. So in the parent that's rendering this list of fruits, when rendering filter out any with a count of 0. I think it's more React-y for a parent to control the rendering of its children, than them controlling the rendering of themselves.

Comment: I will try that, but Luke's solution is not working. I am getting an error in my IDE which breaks my code. It was one of my attempts and I gave up trying. I commented on his answer a screenshot of the attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Comment: @EmileBergeron I can't really apply this with my structure. I don't see how I could. I have edited my post so that you can see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The other way is to not even get to `Facture` by filtering first: `<Factures fruits={this.props.fruits.filter(f => f.count)}/>`. React is data-driven. Data goes from top of the tree to the bottom component, transform the data as needed before passing it to the next component.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks. Filtering before sending down the data is much more easier. You can post as an answer because it fixed it.

Comment: You are missing a few `return` statements in your `render` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a couple of ways:

**Option A: Filter the array of fruits before passing it in as props to `Client`**

This method means you won't need a condition in your children components because you'll only be passing fruits that you want to be rendered as props.

```js
// only keep fruits if fruit.count > 0
render() { <Client fruits={this.state.fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.count > 0}/> }
```

**Option B: Conditional rendering in the `Facture` component**

This method will check every fruit's count and only render the fruits where `fruit.count > 0`.

```js
class Facture extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // if `fruit.count > 0`, render. otherwise, null
    return this.props.fruit.count > 0 ? (
      <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between small">
        <div className="">{this.props.fruit.name}</div>
        <div className="">{"x" + this.props.fruit.count}</div>
      </li>
    ) : null;
  }
}

export default Facture;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Facture extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   render() {
      return (
        {this.props.fruit.count > 0 && 
         <li className='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between small'>
            <div className=''>{this.props.fruit.name}</div>
            <div className=''>{'x' + this.props.fruit.count}</div>
         </li>
        }
      );
   }
}

export default Facture;
```

Comment: It is not working. I get this : https://i.imgur.com/I07zx2C.png

Comment: add this right above the word render constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

Comment: Now it's telling me that `:` is expected.. But now that I comment the constructor part I still get the `:` error instead of the original one in the screenshot. It really looks like the code isn't compiling more than a variable is missing or something.

Comment: take away the ( after the && like above and the ) before the } after the closing li

Comment: It changes nothing. That was my attempt before I posted on here. I'll post a full structure of my code so that it may help to better picture it?