# if statement does nothing while checking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a photo slider, but an if statement doesn't work... I've got 2 if statement. One if statement works perfectly, while the other one does nothing.

Code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

export const Slideshow = () => {
    const partners = ["/partners/logo_wp.jpg", "/partners/logo_van_leeuwen.png",     "/partners/logo_kennelservices.png", "/partners/logo_beckhuis.jpg",     "/partners/logo_kabeldirect.png", "/partners/logo_kremer.png"];

const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

return (
    <div style={{position: "relative"}}>
        <div style={{
            display: "flex",
            transform: `translateX(-${currentImage * 100}%)`,
            transition: "transform .25s ease"
        }}>
            {partners.map(partner => <div
                style={{flexBasis: "33.333%", flexShrink: 0, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <img src={partner} style={{
                    height: '120px'
                }}/>
            </div>)}
        </div>

        {(() => {
            if (!currentImage <= 0) {
                return (
                    <button className={'prev-photo'}
                            style={{position: "absolute", left: 0, top: "50%", transform: 'scale(2)'}}
                            onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage - 1)}>&lt;
                    </button>
                )
            }
        })()}

        {(() => {
            if (!currentImage >= partners.length) {
                return (
                    <button className={'next-photo'}
                            style={{position: "absolute", right: 0, top: "50%", transform: 'scale(2)'}}
                            onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage + 1)}>&gt;</button>
                )
            }
        })}

        <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
            {(currentImage + 1) + '/' + partners.length}
        </div>
    </div>
)
};
```

Here you've my code. The last if statement does nothing. I hope someone can figure out where the error occurs. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb warn "export 'default' (imported as 'Slideshow') was not found in
warn "export 'default' (imported as 'Slideshow') was not found in
warn "export 'default' (imported as 'Slideshow') was not found in

Comment: how did you import `Slideshow`, may be you are using like `import Slideshow from '../../`,  try importing as `import {Slideshow} from '../../....`

Comment: @AkhilAravind import { Slideshow } from '../components/slideshow'

Comment: remove the if block and check whether you can render the component

Comment: @AkhilAravind See my answer below the reaction of Muhammad. He render it perfectly

Comment: could be a typo. Why `! currentImage`? Seems the condition `!currentImage >= partners.length` will always be false.

Comment: @JosephD.Yea stupid me, because I was trying everthing. Even if I try  `currentImage >= partners.length`, I still get nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi      this answer works

see the code live :

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-mountain-18yu8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**you need  to add  `()` to the end of the JSX function   for the right arrow**

**also   use this   conditions instead**

```
if (currentImage < partners.length-1) {
```

and

```
if (currentImage > 0) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this one helped me out! I only changed the 33.333% to 100%

Answer (score 0):

When you do not export your component as default you can not default import it. 
either you can import it as;

```
import {SlideShow} from 'SlideShow';
```

Or export it as default

```
const Slideshow = () => {
    const partners = ["/partners/logo_wp.jpg", "/partners/logo_van_leeuwen.png",     "/partners/logo_kennelservices.png", "/partners/logo_beckhuis.jpg",     "/partners/logo_kabeldirect.png", "/partners/logo_kremer.png"];

const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);

return (
    <div style={{position: "relative"}}>
        <div style={{
            display: "flex",
            transform: `translateX(-${currentImage * 100}%)`,
            transition: "transform .25s ease"
        }}>
            {partners.map(partner => <div
                style={{flexBasis: "33.333%", flexShrink: 0, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <img src={partner} style={{
                    height: '120px'
                }}/>
            </div>)}
        </div>

        {(() => {
            if (!currentImage <= 0) {
                return (
                    <button className={'prev-photo'}
                            style={{position: "absolute", left: 0, top: "50%", transform: 'scale(2)'}}
                            onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage - 1)}>&lt;
                    </button>
                )
            }
        })()}

        {(() => {
            if (!currentImage >= partners.length) {
                return (
                    <button className={'next-photo'}
                            style={{position: "absolute", right: 0, top: "50%", transform: 'scale(2)'}}
                            onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage + 1)}>&gt;</button>
                )
            }
        })}

        <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
            {(currentImage + 1) + '/' + partners.length}
        </div>
    </div>
)
};

export default Slideshow;
```

Also, if currentImage starts from 0. then you have to modify your condition as

```
(!currentImage > partners.length)
```

Comment: That change nothing

Comment: I have updated the answer, you was not exporting your component as default that was the issue.

Comment: I've already imported my Component. He shows my slider and arrows, but I don't want a arrow right if it is my last photo.

Comment: When you are at the last image the length would be 6 right? what will be the value of  currentImage?

Comment: That's exactly what I've done right now. The length is 5, because there are 6 photo's in const partners.

Comment: I mean... that was the same response when I asked my question. Nothing changed yet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not executing the function containing the second `if` statement.

Try to add a `()` at the end, such that it becomes

```js
        {(() => {
            if (!currentImage >= partners.length) {
                return (
                    <button className={'next-photo'}
                            style={{position: "absolute", right: 0, top: "50%", transform: 'scale(2)'}}
                            onClick={() => setCurrentImage(currentImage + 1)}>&gt;</button>
                )
            }
        })()}
```