# Conditional Rendering Inside A Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, rendering

I have seen multiple examples but none of them fit my problem. I want to use conditional rendering inside a functional component. For example, if the user is not logged in and a token is not present in the local storage, when the login form is submitted, I want to display a message that login is invalid.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    return <Typography>Login Invalid</Typography>
    console.log('Login Not possible');
  }
```

For now, I tried to make it a separate function and called it in onSubmit() of my form. But there's no output for that.

```
function ShowError(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    return <Typography>Login Invalid</Typography>
  }
  else{
    console.log('Login Done');
  }
}
        return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation); ShowError()}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >

                        Submit</Button>
                      <br></br>
                      <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            Forgot password?
                    </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                          </Link>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                      {/* <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} >
        <Alert severity="success">
          This is a success message!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar> */}
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
            <Box mt={8}>
              <Copyright />
            </Box>
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

f I do this `{localStorage.getItem('token') && <Typography>Invalid Login</Typography>}`

it will be rendered even before the form is submitted but I only want it to appear if the form is not submitted.
 How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `ternary` statement instead of `if/else`

```
function isLoggedIn(){
  return typeof localStorage.getItem('token') !== 'undefined'
}

...

const isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn()
const [formSubmitted, setSubmit] = useState(false)
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(isLoggedIn)

useEffect(() => {
  if (loggedIn) {
   localStorage.set('token', [token])
  }
}, [loggedIn])

return (
  <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
    {(LoginMutation: any) => (
      ...
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
            Forgot password?
          </Link>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
            {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
          </Link>
        </Grid>
        {!loggedIn && formSubmitted  ? <Typography>Login Invalid</Typography> : null}
      </Grid>
      ...
    )}
  </Mutation>
);

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: Yeah I just edited the question. But wouldn't this render the Typography even before the form is submitted?

Comment: Why don't you store wether the form has been submitted in state and then use that value to decide wether you need to display you login validation message?

Comment: Could you please give me short example on how to do that in my case?

Comment: If I store the form's state separately and then check it inside the form's return again, how would it work? I think it would never work since the condition will always be checked before submitting the form

Comment: 1. If the user is already logged in i.e there is a token in local storage, why would he need to see the login form? 2. If you need to respond when the user has logged in you need to store that value in state so your component can re-render you will also need to respond to the logged in state change by storing the token in localStorage. I've updated my answer to include this. 3. If you update the state the component should re-render and display your Invalid Login component - but you need to hook this up to your form submission handler i.e `handleOpen`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply insert a condition before your final return. I usually do this to show some error.

Let's say your component is called LoginPage. Then -

```
function LoginPage() {
 ...//do something



...//do something

  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    return <Typography>Login Invalid</Typography>
  }

  return(
 <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'column',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();
                    submitForm(LoginMutation)}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        onClick={handleOpen}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px'
                        }}
                      >

                        Submit</Button>
                      <br></br>
                      <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            Forgot password?
                    </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                            {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                          </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        **IF ELSE STATEMENT HERE**
                      </Grid>
                      {/* <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} >
        <Alert severity="success">
          This is a success message!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar> */}
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
            <Box mt={8}>
              <Copyright />
            </Box>
          </Container>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
 )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't work for me. If you see my code, I also made a separate function first and then tried calling it on my form. It gives me no output. If I call the function inside my final return(), after the grid, It doesn't even appear as a function. It's just text. Also, even if it was function, it would just render even before submitting the form. I only want it to check the condition and render when the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderMe(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('token'))
  {
    return <ErrorComponent />
  }else{
    return <Dashboard />
  }
}
return renderMe();
```

this worked for me just fine. i hope this fixes your probleme.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work for me. If you see my code, I also made a separate function first and then tried calling it on my form. It gives me no output. If I call the function inside my final return(), after the grid, It doesn't even appear as a function. It's just text. Also, even if it was function, it would just render even before submitting the form. I only want it to check the condition and render when the form is submitted.

Comment: okeyy why don't u just store the token in state so everytime the state changes 
it rerenders the component again , 
and check if u are calling the method like this { renderMe() } 
i guess you are calling without {} so it shows text ?