# Conditional jsx on react Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to render the following with a condition, but I'm not getting it for some reason:
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

in my {dropdownItem.map (item => (

```
<NavLi>
  <Link to={link}>{name}</Link>
  {visibleMenu[name] && dropdownItem &&
  (
    {dropdownItem.map(item=>(
      <ul>
        <li>
          {item}
        </li>
      </ul>
    ))
    }
  )
  }
</NavLi>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my structure

Comment: {visibleMenu[name] && dropdownItem && dropdownItem.map ... }

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a new list for each item inside of `dropdownItem`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra curly braces in your JSX. Once you open up `{` to tell the JSX that you want to evaluate an expression you don't need to open another one.

```
<NavLi>
  <Link to={link}>{name}</Link>
  {visibleMenu[name] && dropdownItem &&
    dropdownItem.map(item => (
      <ul>
        <li>
          {item}
        </li>
      </ul>
    ))
  }
</NavLi>
```