# why console.log("hello) is printing six times in React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am learning the react hooks and i used the random API for fetching the demo users. can anyone told me why the hello is printed 6 times and also i am not able to use the if statement inside my return statement

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function RandomUser () {
    const [users, setuser] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("fetching api ");
        fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50").then((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then((res)=>{
            setuser(res.results);
            setLoading(false);
        })
    },[])
        console.log("hello");
    return (
        <>
        {loading && <h1>Loading</h1>}
        {users.map((v,i)=>{
            return(
                <li>
                    {v.name.first}
                </li>
            )
        })}
        </>
    );
}

export default RandomUser;
```

[image]

[image: I am getting Expression expected error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `console.log` line is not inside your `useEffect` hook, and therefore is being called every render. React calls render whenever it needs to, so you should not include code that has side effects (except for hooks) inside of functional components.
If you want that log line to be called after you get a result back, then move it up to after `setLoading(false);`

JSX does not support `if` [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) inside JSX literals, but it does support ternary expressions (`condition ? trueValue : falseValue`) and boolean expressions (`condition && trueValue` or `condition || falseValue`), which usually work. Alternatively, you can put your if blocks in small subcomponents, or in helper functions. Just make sure that you always return either a component or `null` from every branch of code. For example to make a loading component:

```
function Loading ({loading=true}) {
  if (loading) return (<h1>Loading...</h1>)
  return null // notice the else is not necessary here
}

//and use it like this:

return(<><Loading loading={loading} /></>)
```

The reason why if statements aren't supported is that they don't have return values (they aren't [expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)), while ternary and boolean expressions do. You can call return from inside an `if` statement, but that causes the whole function to return, not just the `if` statement.

JSX gets complied to something like `React.createComponent(React.Fragment, null, children)`. Imagine what would happen if you put an `if` statement where `children` is. In fact, try something like `console.log(if (true) {true} else {false})` and see what happens. It fails because you have to provide an *expression*, not a *statement* as an argument to a function. (Note though that generally an expression is also a statement, but not always the other way around).

You may find this video helpful: https://en.hexlet.io/courses/intro_to_programming/lessons/expressions/theory_unit

Comment: and what about the if statement , why it is giving error

Comment: I answered both questions :). However, the rule on SO is one question at a time, for future reference.

Comment: Also, your second question is already asked and answered here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs