# Nested if else condition in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to write a nested IF ELSE condition in JSX but its not working. Can anyone please help how to write the below condition in JSX?

```
if (content) {
    if (content.flag) {
        <showSomeComponent />
    }else if (!content.flag) {
        <showSomeOtherComponent />
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it in

```
const asd = content && content.flag ? <ShowSomeComponent /> : <ShowSomeOtherComponent />

const asd = content && content.flag && <ShowSomeComponent /> || <ShowSomeOtherComponent />

return content && content.flag && <ShowSomeComponent /> || <ShowSomeOtherComponent />

return content?.flag ? <ShowSomeComponent /> : <ShowSomeOtherComponent />;
```

Comment: Thanks, Han, I tried this actually like this {content && content.flag ? <showSomeComponent /> : <showSomeOtherComponent />} is this correct?

Comment: You need uppercase for the component's name.

Comment: Yes Dennish you are right my typo. But problem here is the structure of the condition.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `return` statement and [**Uppercased** component name](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component):

```
if (content) {
  if (content.flag) {
    return <ShowSomeComponent />;
  } else {
    return <ShowSomeOtherComponent />;
  }
}
```

> Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.
>   React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

Or with optional chaining and ternary operator:

```
// return content && content.flag ? <ShowSomeComponent /> : <ShowSomeOtherComponent />
return content?.flag ? <ShowSomeComponent /> : <ShowSomeOtherComponent />;
```