# How to set if-else statement in a React function Return()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning if else statement in React,

So i want the button in the table to appear if the variable "step" is set to 1, other than that the button (and the row) wont appear. What method is the best to implement this if else?

```
function DeletableGroupRow({
  student,
  hasDeleteButton = false,
  onDeleteStudent,
  step,
}) {
  DeletableGroupRow.propTypes = {
    student: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    hasDeleteButton: PropTypes.bool,
    onDeleteStudent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
  const handleDeleteClick = () => {
    onDeleteStudent(student.id);
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{student.nim}</td>
      <td>{student.name}</td>
      <td>{student.class}</td>
      <td>{student.peminatan.abbrev}</td>
      // if the variable "step" is set to 1 then this td appears
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-default"
          onClick={handleDeleteClick}
          disabled={!hasDeleteButton}
        >
          Hapus
        </button>
      </td>
      //
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 2):

here's how to do a conditional rendering

```
<td>
 { step === 1 ? 
    <button type="button" 
    className="btn btn-default" 
    onClick={handleDeleteClick} 
    disabled={!hasDeleteButton}>Hapus</button> 
    : null 
 }
            
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks!  is the ```' : null'``` in the code the ```else``` case?

Comment: yes, this is called a ternary operator, which acts like if / else

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly there is two way we can do it (Known to me).

```
function DeletableGroupRow({
  student,
  hasDeleteButton = false,
  onDeleteStudent,
  step,
}) {
  DeletableGroupRow.propTypes = {
    student: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    hasDeleteButton: PropTypes.bool,
    onDeleteStudent: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
  const handleDeleteClick = () => {
    onDeleteStudent(student.id);
  };

  if (step === 1) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{student.nim}</td>
      <td>{student.name}</td>
      <td>{student.class}</td>
      <td>{student.peminatan.abbrev}</td>
      // if the variable "step" is set to 1 then this td appears
      <td>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-default"
          onClick={handleDeleteClick}
          disabled={!hasDeleteButton}
        >
          Hapus
        </button>
      </td>
      //
    </tr>
  );
}
} else {
 return </>
}
```

OR

```
return (
  { step === 1 && <tr>...</tr> }
  { step === 0 && </>}
);
```

</> may or may not be needed, people with sound expertise in react may correct this.

Comment: tried both your solution and can confirm both works!

Comment: Glad to know that. Mark it as answered if you feel it helped so others can benefit from this as well. @Buffaurus

Answer (score 0):

you can use `&&` operator which mean `if and only if` is `true`. It is a shorthand to `if-else` but simpler and readable.
But if you want render something else if your condition is `false` then use `if-else`.

```
{step === 1 && (
 <td>
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-default"
      onClick={handleDeleteClick}
      disabled={!hasDeleteButton}
    >
      Hapus
    </button>
  </td>
 )}
```

Comment: thanks! this one (if and only if condition) is new to me and i think this is the more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

you can't use if / else statement inside the return i think. You have two possibity, ternary inside rendering like this

```
 { 
       step === 1 &&
  <td>
          <button type="button" 
          className="btn btn-default" 
          onClick={handleDeleteClick} 
          disabled={!hasDeleteButton}>
            {'Hapus'}
          </button> 
           
 </td>
}
```

Or a sub component like  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Comment: Yes you can. check out the first comment.