# Using react JSX and HTML in a ternary operation and cannot get it to display it correctly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

the variable twitter_username resolves to either a username or null.

```
 {{twitter_username}?<p>@{twitter_username}</p>:null}
```

I want this to display @username if there is a username or nothing at all if the value is null.
If there is a username it displays fine but if the return is null I get an
@ instead of nothing.

```
 {{twitter_username}?<p>{twitter_username}</p>:null}
```

this code returns the username if there is a username and is blank when there is none.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Comment: `{twitter_username}` creates an object `{ twitter_username: twitter_username }` which is always truthy in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a nice and easy way to do it `{ twitter_username && (<p>@{twitter_username}</p>) }`

Here the left part of the ternary operator will continue to the right only if the first part (twitter_username) if defined. The right part is a return statement who returns jsx