# if and else if statement inside JSX curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to put an `if else` statement inside JSX curly braces like:

```
<div>
  {
    if (condition) {
      <h1>FOO</h1>
    } else {
      <h2>BAR</h1>
    }
  }
</div>
```

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljil5.png).

But I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTq0t.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

you can not use if keyword inside JSX. So to solve your issue

```
{
  post.weather[0].main === "Haze" && <WiDayHaze size={100} color="black">
  post.weather[0].main === "Sunny" && <WiSunrise size={100} color="black">
}
```

Comment: i want to put 26 statement so who can i put 26 statement in this