# I keep getting this error Objects are not valid as a React child {} If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is currently how my code looks

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
 
  state = {
  apiData: []
  }
 
  render() {   
    
  console.log('api data is')
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
        <h1 id="title">hello something</h1></center>
        <h1 id="date">{this.state.apiData.title}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dece3d333000052002b9037')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          apiData: data
        })
      })        
      console.log("component fetched data")
  }
}
 
export default App
```

I get this error when I try access something that has a value but when I do this

```
     <h1 id="date">{this.state.apiData.date}</h1>
```

It works

not too sure how to fix as everything I have seen thus far is for data they have created through a const or let as opposed to fetching data from an API

Comment: What's `title`? Is it an object?

Comment: Try `this.state.apiData.title.rendered`

Comment: I have tried to do this and I still get an error this one to be exact TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Also, since the data isn't ready at the first render, you'll need a condition, which in JavaScript can be expressed in different ways [to avoid 'cannot read property of undefined' errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14782232/1218980).

Comment: and possibly [conditional rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44046037/1218980) with React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a null check `{this.state.apiData.title?.rendered}`

Update: Try to open the link you're fetching the data from and follow the paths inside, for hero_image you need `{this.state.apiData.acf?.hero_image.url}`

Comment: This would pass `undefined` potentially, which causes an error.

Comment: It should just return undefined

Comment: This actually worked for the title but not for anything else that has the same data set e.g         <h4>{this.state.apiData.hero_image?.url}</h4>
 This doesn't even render anything at all.

Comment: But I am wondering why ? actually allows the title I want to be rendered to be rendered

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Nadia this has worked perfectly thank you! Do you have any resources on the null check I have never seen this before

Comment: Happy to help. ?. is called optional chaining - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: If this helped, you should mark it as the accepted answer. Here's MDN on optional chaining: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova beat me by 22 seconds!

Comment: @LoganDevine now there is choice of 2 identical links :D

Comment: For some reason some of them are not rendering on the page am I potentially using the wrong path way e.g         <h4>{this.state.apiData._embedded?.author.name}</h4>

Comment: Would I need to use .map as "widgets": [
      {
        "acf_fc_layout": "paragraph",
        "paragraph": "<p>As much as we probably don’t like to admit it, the real soundtrack to our daily lives isn’t Lizzo or the latest installment of ... ] is an array

Comment: 'author` is an array, so it needs to be `author[0].name`, not sure what you mean about widgets

Answer (score 3):

`apiData.title` is of type `Object`, not an `Array` of JSX children or strings.

You need to use `apiData.title.rendered`, as shown in this snippet of response data from the API:

```json
  "title": {
    "rendered": "Whatsapp and Facebook Messenger: how group chat is changing the dynamic of our friendships"
  },
```

Comment: I have tried to do this and I still get an error this one to be exact TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

Comment: That means `apiData.title` is undefined. Can you edit your post with the full contents of `apiData` as you would get from logging it?

Comment: `componentDidMount` runs ***after*** the component renders, so `apiData` itself is just `[]`. You need to fetch the data before it renders.

Comment: The data has been fetched already I have access to the data but its the type of data that I think is causing some trouble as it is an object

Comment: Yes. Can you please log `apiData.title` in your render event?

Answer (score -1):

As render fire before state set so you need to check before state update and use condition or && on "this.state.apiData.title" like this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 
  state = {
  apiData: []
  }
 
  render() {   
    
  console.log('api data is')
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
        <h1 id="title">hello something</h1></center>
        <h1 id="date">{this.state.apiData.title && this.state.apiData.title.rendered}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5dece3d333000052002b9037')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          apiData: data
        })
      })        
      console.log("component fetched data")
  }
}
 
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App  />
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```