# React & Next js: Only render div if prop contains value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, conditional-statements, rendering

Im working through my app, but I'm stuck on an issue.

I have some data from contentful which I passed as props to my component. There is one piece of data that I only want to render if it contains any value.

This work to an extent, however, the background still shows.

```
<div className="text-white font-base text-xs text-center p-1.5 bg-black">
   {`${mrr ? mrr : ""}`}
</div>
```

[picture of the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNOCJ.png)

[picture of the frontend 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MYlM.png)

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44046037) basically: ```{mrr && <div className="...">{mrr}</div>}``` or ```{mrr ? <div className="...">{mrr}</div> : <></>}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
{mrr && (
    <div className="text-white font-base text-xs text-center p-1.5 bg-black">
        {mrr}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Perfect! That works. Could you explain how that works? Just trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

@famouslastwords
The TopW3's answer is correct. I will try to explain the code.

The below text will be rendered only when mrr is true. It is same as executing below code:

```
const result = true && anything; // result = anything
```

or

```
const result = false && anything // result = false

{mrr && (
    <div className="text-white font-base text-xs text-center p-1.5 bg-black">
        {mrr}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah tested it out and it worked perfectly!