# React, how to use if condition inside a div to change its className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get data using API and loop it for banner images.
I got the data. And it is working fine. Here is the code to get the data.

```
///Retrieving data using API
const [post, setPost] = useState(null);    
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(global.url+'api/welcome').then(response => {
      setPost(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Now, I want to show images in the banner. In the first loop div class needs to `<div className="carousel-item active">` as shown in the image. From the second loop active need to be removed to be like: `<div className="carousel-item">`.

```
////Looping for banner images
    post[1].data.map((banner_image) => (
     <div>    
       <div className="carousel-item active">
        <img src="image source here" className="d-block w-100" alt="" />
       </div>
     </div> ))
```

In this case how to use the `if` condition? I am very new to React Js.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Also it might be prettier to define your URL as 
`\`${global.url}/api/welcome\`` instead of `global.url+'/api/welcome'`.

Comment: You will see that none of the answers actually use an if-statements. This is because if-else statements are not possible to use inside jsx. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs

See also the react.js docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do conditions in your JSX as below. Notice the `{}` for `className`.

```
 post[1].data.map((banner_image, index) => (
     <div>    
       <div className={"carousel-item " + (index === 0 ? "active" : "")}>
        <img src="image source here" className="d-block w-100" alt="" />
       </div>
     </div> ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
////Looping for banner images
    post[1].data.map((banner_image, idx) => (
     <div key={idx}>    
       <div className={`carousel-item ${idx === 0 ? "active" : ""}`}>
        <img src="image source here" className="d-block w-100" alt="" />
       </div>
     </div> ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals in JSX.

```js
post[1].data.map((banner_image, index) => (
     <div key={`uui-${index}`}>    
       <div className={`carousel-item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
        <img src="image source here" className="d-block w-100" alt="" />
       </div>
     </div> ))
```